# XSL: Calling specific Element from Multiple Instances of one Schema

Tags: xslt, xpath, xsd

I created a component named "BusLocationLinks" it stores the name of the business as well as the coordinates for a map I created.

I have nearly 50 business locations with that same schema (BusLocationsLinks) and only want to list the element "Business Name" of all components components of that name. I've tried everything but can not make them all display. ANY ADVICE?

Here's my current code:

```
 <xsl:template name="BusLocationLinks">
      <xsl:for-each select="BusLocationLinks/BusinessName">
    <li class="active">
      <xsl:value-of select="BusinessName" />
    </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

my xml code looks similar to such:

```
<BusLocationLinks>
    <BusinessName>Star Property</BusinessName>
</BusLocationLinks>
```

Comment: It is likely that the `BusinessName` elements are all children of `BusLocationLinks` and that you don't have any `BusLocationLinks` that are children of `BusLocationLinks`. It would be helpful if you posted an example XML file.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your XML it is difficult to diagnose the problem. However, it is likely that you have the following structure:

```
<BusLocationLinks>
    <BusinessName>name1</BusinessName>
    <BusinessName>name2</BusinessName>
    <BusinessName>name3</BusinessName>
</BusLocationLinks>
```

If that is the case, then you should adjust your XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:template name="BusLocationLinks">
  <xsl:for-each select="BusinessName">
    <li class="active">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The body of an `xsl:for-each` instruction resets the context node to be one of the nodes in the selected node set (a different one each time the body of the for-each is evaluated).

In your example, that means that within the body of the for-each, the current node is one of the `BusLocationLinks/BusinessName` elements you selected.  Your loop creates a list-item element for each of them (check your output, I expect you'll see them there) containing the value of the `BusinessName` child of the context node.  The context node matches the expression `BusLocationLinks/BusinessName`, so you are looking for the values of nodes which match `BusLocationLinks / BusinessName / BusinessName`.  If you don't have any nodes that match the expression `BusLocationLinks / BusinessName / BusinessName`, you'll be getting empty `li` elements.

Try `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.

Comment: Thank you.  So the conjectures Mads Hansen and I made about your XML structure were correct.  You should now see, looking at the answers you've gotten, what is wrong with your code and how to fix it.